# Replace word with another in whole directory

Tags: vim

I need to pass through all the files in a directory in order to replace a word with another. For instance, if I have three files

- `test1.py`
- `test2.py`
- `test3.py`

and all of them use `word1` in which I want to replace with `word2`. I know I could grep the directory, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do it. Could anyone be able to tell me how I can do it?

In fact, I think we could use `:s` for a file, but not for several files in a directory. Is there a command line or a plugin I could use for doing such task?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11442/205 http://askubuntu.com/questions/883885/replace-word-with-another-in-whole-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should works:

`sed -i 's/^.*looking_word/new_word/' nameOFfile.py`

It should help u understood: 
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

This will take a backup of all python files and make changes permanently in the file.

```
sed -i.bak 's/word1/word2/g' *.py
```

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied).  The default
>   operation mode is to  break  symbolic  and  hard  links.
>
> The syntax of the s command (which stands for "substitute") is:
>   ‘s/regexp/replacement/flags’.

more details here http://www.computerhope.com/unix/used.htm

Comment: nice, but could you explain your command?

Comment: if you want in vim, you can refer this post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804405/search-and-replace-in-vim-across-all-the-project-files